# EF not creating AspNet Identity tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have a simple aspnet Identity schema but im not able to create the tables of Identity in my Database.
Heres the main classes used by the MVC website for identity:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (modelBuilder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");
        }

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser> table =
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");

        table.Property((ApplicationUser u) => u.UserName).IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany<IdentityUserRole>((ApplicationUser u) => u.Roles);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey((IdentityUserRole r) =>
            new { UserId = r.UserId, RoleId = r.RoleId }).ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

        EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserLogin> entityTypeConfiguration =
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey((IdentityUserLogin l) =>
                new
                {
                    UserId = l.UserId,
                    LoginProvider = l.LoginProvider,
                    ProviderKey
                        = l.ProviderKey
                }).ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");

        entityTypeConfiguration.HasRequired<IdentityUser>((IdentityUserLogin u) => u.User);
        EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserClaim> table1 =
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");

        table1.HasRequired<IdentityUser>((IdentityUserClaim u) => u.User);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");

        EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityRole> entityTypeConfiguration1 =
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");

        entityTypeConfiguration1.Property((IdentityRole r) => r.Name).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

When I try to login, the OnModelCreating method executes but when i go to the database the tables are not created and I get the error "Invalid Column name AspNetUsers". 
Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To your Global.Asax add

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

This will drop and re-create database on every model change.

Read more about [Entity Framework Database Initialization Strategies](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In my case in test development environment:

Removing the table "__MigrationHistory" solved it.

For some reason it was blocking the creation of the other tables.